# Comprehensive problem

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-meaning

Would you please explain grammar of this sentence? I am confused about "as" in this sentence.

> Strange as this behaviour may be , there is a very good reason for it.

Comment: "Strange as this behaviour may be"  is an idiomatic preposition phrase functioning as a concessive adjunct. It can be paraphrased as "Though this behaviour may be strange, there is a very goof reason for it".

Answer (score 3):

Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p72) has an explanation for this construction in the section *'as and though: special word order'*:

> *As* and *though* can be used in a special structure after an adjective, adverb or noun. In this case they both mean 'although', and
>   suggest an emphatic contrast. (In AmE only *as* is normally used like
>   this; *though* is unusual.)
>
> - Cold as/though it was, we went out. (= Although it was very cold,...)
> - Strange though it may seem, I don't like watching cricket.

So the sentence *Strange as this behaviour may be, there is a very good reason for it* can be understood as:

> - Although this behaviour may be strange, there is a good reason for it.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways this sentence would be *grammatically correct* usage of as/though:

> As strange as this behaviour may be, there is a very good reason for it.

or

> Though this behaviour may be strange, there is very good reason for it.

Having said that, the following idiomatic expressions, as hybrids of the above grammatically correct versions, are now commonly accepted (as Shoe’s answer shows):

> Strange though this behaviour may be...

and

> Strange as this behaviour may be...

When explaining English usage as a second language, these are both ‘acceptable’ formats, because they are commonly used. But when explaining *correct* English usage, both of these uses are notably missing from the examples.

Because technically, this is neither a *correct* use of ‘though’ [(Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/although-or-though), nor a *correct* use of ‘as’ [(perfect English grammar)](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/as-and-like.html).

Infinity suggested adding a comma before ‘as’, which would have complied with the use of ‘as’ as a conjunctive (3) when talking about similarity - but this is not the case here. The only other correct use of ‘as’ when talking about *similarity* is in ‘as adjective as’ expressions (4):

> We need to use 'as' with expressions like 'as much as' and by 'as
>   adjective as'. This is also talking about similarity. These
>   expressions can be followed by a subject and a verb or a noun or
>   preposition. 
>   John loves spicy food as much as I do. 
>   Lucy travels as much as me. 
>   She's as clever as her sister is. 
>   London's not as big as Mexico City. - ‘As and Like’, *Perfect English Grammar*

The other correct uses of ‘as’ are to mean ‘while’ or ‘because’, or with a noun to show someone’s position - none of which apply here.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that there is something *ungrammatical* about the clause "strange as this behaviour may be". If so, could you [edit] your answer to explain what rule is being broken?

Comment: @Chappo - The rule being broken is word usage - see edits.